# Does Fisher linear discriminant analysis (LDA) require normal distribution of the data in each class?

Tags: classification, assumptions, discriminant-analysis

Does Fisher linear discriminant analysis really require the data distribution in each category to be normal?

I see two versions. The first one states that it requires the normal distribution and that the objective function is the misclassification rate.

The second one states that the objective function is the ratio between within-class variance and between-class variance, and this version does not seem to require normality.

What is the point here?

Answer (score 4):

When data is normally distributed LDA guarantees a solution, that minimizes the expected error. It can be applied to non-normal data, but then there are no guarantees about the generalization error.

Edit:
I just found in Wikipedia that:
"The terms Fisher's linear discriminant and LDA are often used interchangeably, although Fisher's original article actually describes a slightly different discriminant, which does not make some of the assumptions of LDA such as normally distributed classes or equal class covariances".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis

Comment: And logistic regression makes far fewer assumptions, hence it's less clear why LDA is still used as much as it is.

Comment: I think LDA is not used as much as it used to be, when access to computing power was more difficult. LDA offers an analytical solution, while logistic regression requires iterative optimization.

Comment: Iterative optimization means on the average making 5 passes at the dataset instead of the one that LDA requires.  It's very much worth the time.

Comment: +1, but just to make sure that everything is clear: LDA will find the discriminant axis (single axis in case of only two classes) that maximizes the ratio of between-class and within-class variances. This will be true for any dataset whatsoever. In case the classes are Gaussian *with identical covariance*, LDA solution will be optimal for classification. If these two assumptions are not true, then such optimality is not guaranteed.

Comment: Just to say this another way, the posterior probabilities of class membership will be accurate only if the multivariate normality and equal variance assumptions hold.